# Is it possible to find unitary $\boldsymbol{\Theta}$ and scalar $\lambda$ such that $\boldsymbol{\Theta a} = \lambda \boldsymbol{b}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, unitary-matrices

Given vectors $\boldsymbol{a}$ and $\boldsymbol{b} \ne \boldsymbol{0}$ in the same Hilbert space, does

$$\boldsymbol{\Theta a} = \lambda \boldsymbol{b}$$

always hold for some unitary $\boldsymbol{\Theta}$ and *real* scalar $\lambda$?

If the answer is yes and there are multiple solution pairs, how to find $\boldsymbol{\Theta}_\max$ that corresponds to $\lambda_\max$?

The problem looks simple but the closest I have in mind is the [generalized eigenvalue problem.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.11240.pdf) Thank you for any hint!

Edit: Sorry my description was misleading. I made some very naive attempts (1) using pseudo-inverse and (2) on the 2x2 case where the unitary matrix has a closed-form expression.

Comment: Yes it does, with $\lambda=\pm1$ and $\lambda_\max=1.$ Please edit your post to include your attempts. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: I can see you put three tags related to matrices, but this property holds more generally in any Hilbert space, not necessarily finite-dimensional.

Comment: @Anne Bauval Thanks for the tips. I guess you meant $\lambda = \pm \lVert \boldsymbol{a} \rVert / \lVert \boldsymbol{b} \rVert$.

Comment: Sorry I was using the wrong words. By "size" I meant dimension.

Comment: Oh, I thought they were vectors of the same norm, in the same (Hilbert) space. Please edit your post to specify the context, then. It could be $a\in H_1,b\in H_2$ where $H_1,H_2$ are isomorphic Hilbert spaces (not necessarily finite-dimensional).  Note that if $b=0,$ $a$ has to be $0$ also. So, better assume $b\ne0.$ This way, you can prove your conjecture, with $\lambda = \pm \lVert \boldsymbol{a} \rVert / \lVert \boldsymbol{b} \rVert,$ as you wrote.